# How to send a value from from one script to another on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having an issue with dealing with some values that I want to send to.

The thing is that I want the total value of the time transcurred after quitting the game. When the player logs in, that value is multiplied with the money. So if the player connects after 30 minutes, the player will earn the value of 30 minutes multiplied with the money. Worked with JSON Serialization, public static, and PlayerPrefs but nothing.

PlayerPrefs and Serialization seem working but it only records the time stored before storing. For example, if the player connects after 5 seconds then 20 seconds, the second time it gets the value of 5 seconds and not 20 seconds.

Script A:

```cs
public SaveManager save_manager;
public DateTime new_time, old_time;
public TimeSpan gold_reward_time;
public float current_boostValue_gameplay;

private float minutes_booster_gameplay;
private float seconds_booster_gameplay;
private bool is_stopped_booster_gameplay;

private void Start()
{
    new_time = DateTime.Now;
    old_time = DateTime.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("timeData"));
    gold_reward_time = new_time - old_time;
    Get_sum_of_time_reward();
}
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    Application.Quit();
    Sum_of_time_passed();
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("timeData", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
public void Get_sum_of_time_reward()
{
    double time_hour    = Convert.ToDouble(gold_reward_time.Hours);
    double time_minutes = Convert.ToDouble(gold_reward_time.Minutes);
    double time_seconds = Convert.ToDouble(gold_reward_time.Seconds);
    
    double sum_of_time_values = time_hour + time_minutes + time_seconds;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("totalRewardTime",sum_of_time_values.ToString());
}
```

Script B:

```cs
public void Calculate_time_as_gold()
{
    string load_resident_menu_data = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/resident_menu_data.json");
    resident_data = Json_helper.FromJson<Resident_menu_data>(load_resident_menu_data);

    string load_automation_menu_data = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/automation_menu_data.json");
    automation_data = Json_helper.FromJson<Automation_menu_data>(load_automation_menu_data);

    sum_of_all_per_sec = resident_data[0].resident_gold_per_sec + automation_data[0].automation_gold_per_sec;
    sum_of_time_passed = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("totalRewardTime"));
    result_reward_after_time = sum_of_all_per_sec * sum_of_time_passed;

    Debug.Log("total value 1 = " + double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("RewardTimeValue")));
    reward_gold_text.text = Math.Truncate(result_reward_after_time).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [PlayerPrefs.Save](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html) says you don't need to call it manually in OnApplicationQuit. Good.
2. Call `Application.Quit();` at last in `OnApplicationQuit`. Otherwise your changes may not be saved I guess.
3. If you save the time like this: `double sum_of_time_values = time_hour + time_minutes + time_seconds;` wouldn't 20 minutes look the same as 20 seconds?
   Why not simply add the `Time.deltaTime` in Update() to a variable? Time will be in seconds.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, switched the order but nothing, it prints me value of 20 seconds and saves it, but the value loaded is the that is stored before saving that value of 20 and when I load the game again it loads the value of 20.

Comment: I don't see what you are doing in "Get_sum_of_time_reward". Also you are logging "RewardTimeValue" that I cannot see anywhere. I am assuming you are talking about `totalRewardTime`. Try to call "PlayerPrefs.Save()" just to be sure.

Comment: sorry, edited it already, I am trying to send those values, from Script A double sum_of_time_values = time_hour + time_minutes + time_seconds; to Script B  sum_of_time_passed, but it seems not working at all, I think it should be a better way to send that data. It is wrong to pass a value through PlayerPrefs right?

Comment: Thanks for helping, just solved it setting PlayerPrefs on Awake from Script A and getting in on Start from Script B

Comment: Now I see.1st Alternative: Set the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) so that ScriptB always runs after Script A. So you can use `Start()` in both. Awake should work in your case though.
2nd alternative: after setting value in Script A, call `Calculate_time_as_gold` in Script B, from Script A. (You need a reference, or a singleton pattern.)